# better looking, cleare reports

Tags: reporting

I have a report (Summary format) which is sent to all managers each morning.
I get many complains that the report (viewed in the email client) is not clear enough and does not look good.
Are there any other options for these reports, which will also be sent periodically?

Comment: Could you be more specific.  What do they not like about the reports.  What is 'not clear' and what 'doesn't look good'?  What problem are we trying to solve.

Comment: From experience, I agree that emailed reports are ugly. I'm not aware of anything you can do to improve the appearance without custom coding or using an add-on, though.

Comment: Salesforce reports are not very configurable. Maybe someone can suggest a good third-party analytics app.